# Dynamically require a phase 1 (for-syntax) variable in Racket

Tags: macros, racket

Let's say I have some module `foo.rkt` that provides `x` at phase 1.

```
#lang racket
(begin-for-syntax
  (define x 5)
  (provide x))
```

When you run `(module->exports "foo.rkt")` you get back `((1 (x ())))`, meaning that `x` is provided at phase 1 and no other bindings are provided.

Now, in another module I could statically import `x` during run time using `for-template`:

```
#lang racket
(require (for-template "foo.rkt"))
x ; => 5
```

But this is static, and so it will always happen.

If this was at phase 0 I could use `dynamic-require`. But it seems like you can only use `dynamic-require` to run phase 1 code, not get any values from that ran code.

There is also `dynamic-require-for-syntax`, but I could never manage to work.

Finally, there's also `namespace-require`, but then it brings it into the namespace's phase 1, rather than phase 0. So I could do something like `(eval '(begin-for-syntax (writeln x))`, but that will only print the value of `x`, not return it.

There's also `namespace-variable-value`, but it also only seems to return values at phase 0.

So, is there anyway that I can dynamically (not statically) import a phase 1 variable from a module?

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a way, but its kind of disgusting.

First of all, we need to make a base namespace, so something like `(define ns (make-base-namespace))` will do the trick.

Next, I would actually recommend using `namespace-require/expansion-time` rather than `namespace-require`. It will only instantiate the module (aka only run phase 1 code).

Doing this, `x` is not imported into the namespace, but at phase 1, so we can write a macro to 'smuggle' it from phase 1 to phase 0 through 3d syntax.

The macro is going to look something like:

```
(eval '(define-syntax (cheater-x stx)
         #`'#,(datum->syntax #f x)))
```

And now you can just do `(eval 'cheater-x)` to get the value of `x`.

Overall your code should look something like this:

```
(define (dynamic-require-from-syntax module binding)
  (define ns (make-base-namespace))
  (parameterize ([current-namespace ns])
    (namespace-require 'racket)
    (namespace-require/expansion-time module)
    (eval `(define-syntax (cheater-x stx)
              #`'#,(datum->syntax #f ,binding)))
    (eval 'cheater-x)))
(dynamic-require-from-syntax "foo.rkt" 'x) ; => 5
```

Obviously you could set up this function to use the same namespace on multiple calls so that it doesn't re-instantiate the module every time you call it. But that's a different answer.

Comment: This doesn't work if `x` is a list like `(list 5 6)`. I wonder if the `` `', `` pattern would help here?

Comment: Okay ``(datum->syntax stx `',,binding)`` ?

Comment: Ah, good catch, ``#`'#,(datum->syntax #f x)))`` does seem to work though. I'll update the answer.